# Conditional forward fill between integer values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe column of integer values, with empty NaNs between them. i want to forward fill between the start of a new integer and the last instance of that same integer.

```
0   NaN
1   2.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   2.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   3.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  3.0
12  NaN
13  NaN
14  4.0
15  NaN
16  4.0
```

So my resultant dataframe would look like this below. How would i do this? My first approach was using enumerate and conditional statements with isinstance(x,int).

```
0   NaN
1   2.0
2   2.0
3   2.0
4   2.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   3.0
8   3.0
9   3.0
10  3.0
11  3.0
12  NaN
13  NaN
14  4.0
15  4.0
16  4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `ffill` + `bfill` with `mask`

```
i = s.ffill()
i.mask(i != s.bfill())

0     NaN
1     2.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    NaN
13    NaN
14    4.0
15    4.0
16    4.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

`s` is your column.
I really like the conciseness of this.